# Good: How can I run app on android if its showing this error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling

While running the app on an android device it directly throws an error

> - 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart':Failed assertion: line 350 pos 7: '(displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&........)': Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.

I verified every single line of code and double checked any of the possible syntax errors that might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Re-download Flutter SDK. It seems you have an error with Flutter SDK maybe you changed or deleted something in text_theme.dart file. If you don't want to download SDK. You can replace only text_theme.dart file with the new one with the same version (if you have an existing SDK archive).